# ¿Como re calcular datos ya registrados en MySql cuando edito o elimino un registro anterior?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

tengo una tabla movimientos  donde registro entrada y salida de  productos cada registro tiene su cantidad(entrada o salida) y su stock actual  hasta ahí funciona correctamente ahora pues quiero pasar a la parte de editar y me preguntaba si a la hora de editar la columna de cantidad movimiento me pueda re calcular todos los registros siguientes la formula que uso es esta : //

primero inserto un registro
los datos que digito son p unit(precio unitario), cant mov(cantidad movimiento)
// para  hallar el 'saldo stock' en registro nuevo solo copeo la 'cant mov'
 el 'valor mov(s/) se halla multiplicando  'p unit' * 'cant mov' 
el  'valor stock(s/)' se halla multiplicando 'p unit' * 'saldo stock'.

en entrada  para hallar el 'saldo stock' se suma 'cant mov'(de la misma fila) + 
'saldo stock'(de la fila anterior)
para  'valor mov(s/)' y valor stock (s/) es lo mismo que registro nuevo. hací sucesivamente con los proximos registro que insertaria, en salida es igual que entrada solo que en vez de sumar se resta saldo stcok(antiguo) - (cant mov).

algo haci como este excel

aqui se muestran las entradas insertados sin editar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego cambie la cant mov del segundo y se actualizaron su valor mov y valor stock de esa fila y dela  fila que sigue

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero saber si es posible hacer  eso con mysql javascript php ? y si tubieran un ejemplo parecido me seria de mucha ayuda que lo compartieran

Comment: Tus imagenes no son iguales a lo que contas. No se entiende si queres cambiar registros que ya existian? o registros nuevos siempre? igual ojo, una db no es un excel, y no funciona de la misma forma. Y si, es muy probable que sea posible, pero vas a tener que intentarlo y te podemos ayudar si tenes problemas.

Comment: quiero cambiar los registro que ya existen pero solo los que fueron insertados depues del registro que quiero editar , ya tengo todos los datos en un modal editar  y puedo editar esa fila pero no se como a la vez editar todas las siguientes , tienes un ejemplo parecido a lo que trato de hacer ?

Comment: ya edite la pregunta si  no me deje entender por favor me avisan

Comment: IMHO tratar de manejar una base de datos como una planilla excel, no es algo facil ni comodo. porque esa no es justamente la funcionalidad de una db. Si podes ser mucho mas especifico, y dar algun ejemplo de porque queres que una db haga esto, podriamos ayudarte.Si no, pasate por el [chat], donde seguro se te podran dar ideas

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es utilizar Triggers en el insert que actualicen el campo de stock de esta manera cada vez que se inserte un registro en la tabla puedes recalcular y actualizar los datos que requieras.

O cargar los datos necesarios previamente para generar los resultados e insetarlos junto con el nuevo registro.